# Raster calculations with iteration

Tags: raster, modis, land-surface-temperature

I have two sets of raster images, how can I do some raster calculations with iteration?

For example, I got TERAA and AQUA land surface temperature(MOD11A1/MYD11A1) images on the same date, and there are many other pairs like this. But there are some pixels which are no data in the image(raster value = 0). So I want to "merge" them to fill the missing part by raster average calculation, and finally so that I can get more complete daily LST image.

However, I don't know how to do this in ArcMap or Python, is there any code or tool to complete the calculation? In ArcMap the Model Builder can only set one iterator at a time.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Thanks for guiding, I am thinking about this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to solve this problem with raster::overlay in R.

```
library(raster)
r.1 <- raster("F:/Data/MODIS/MOD11A1_2003_01_01.tif")
r.2 <- raster("F:/Data/MODIS/MYD11A1_2003_01_01.tif")

th <- function(x, y) {
  if (x==0){y} 
  else {
    if(y==0){x}
    else{
      round((x+y)/2)
    }
    }
  }

out <- raster::overlay(r.1, r.2,
                       fun = Vectorize(th),
                       filename = "F:/Data/TEMP/SNDPPT_out1.tif", 
                       datatype = "FLOAT", 
                       options  = "COMPRESS=DEFLATE")

out
```